# Typescript conditional function param type error

Tags: typescript

I am facing a problem in TS. Where if I have a type which has a property of a function with conditional types, I cannot create an object with that type where that function is not conditional. For example:

`type TP = { a: string; b: (z: string | number) => void; }`

and if I create a variable of this type

`const l: TP = { a: 'a', b: (z: number): void => {}, };`

if throws an error that Type 'Type '(z: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(z: string | number) => void'..
Shouldn't this be a valid approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a function to `b` that only accepts `number` as its parameter, which is more specific than the original function type in `TP`. TypeScript's type checking correctly identifies that this assignment is not valid because it would potentially break type safety.

You should either include both types in the function prototype, or use generic types, like so;

```js
type TP<T> = { a: string; b: (z: T) => void; }

const l1: TP<number> = { a: 'a', b: (z: number): void => {} };
const l2: TP<string> = { a: 'a', b: (z: string): void => {} };
```